# Deriving a function that includes the absolute value of a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

I have the function

$$f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R},f(x)= |1 - F(x)|,$$

with $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{C}$.

Is there a way to express the gradient $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ in terms of $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ without having to explicitly calculate $f(x)$ for a given $F(x)$?

Comment: Is $F(x) \neq 1$?

Comment: Yes, $F(x)$ is $\neq 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for...

If $f(x) = |g(x)|$ and $g(x) \neq 0$, we have

$f(x) = \sqrt{u(x)^2+ v(x)^2}$, where $u,v$ are the real and imaginary parts of $g$. Differentiating gives
$Df(x) = {1 \over f(x)} (u(x) Du(x) + v(x) Dv(x))$, which we can write as
$Df(x) = {1 \over f(x)} \operatorname{re} (\overline{g(x)} Dg(x))$.

In the above example, we have $g(x) = F(x)-1$, so this becomes
$Df(x) = {1 \over f(x)} \operatorname{re} ( (\overline{F(x)}-1)DF(x) ) $.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!